# Use ansible command module to parse json output from shell program

Tags: json, azure, ansible

I have the following Ansible code which reads input from the 'az' command in azure. I basically want to use it to see when resource groups are done creating my VMS.

```html
#!/usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
---
- name: Firewall Rules
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    iscbr: false

  tasks:
  - name: Register status of group x
    command: az group deployment list -g Tes1Pod
    register: azdeployment

  - name:
    set_fact:
      provisioningstatus: "{{ (azdeployment.stdout|from_json) }}"


  - name: debug provisioningstatus
    debug:
      var: "{{item}}"
    with_items: "{{provisioningstatus.properties}}"


  # - name: Debug stuff
  #   debug:
  #     msg: " item.provisioningState"
  #   with_items: "{{provisioningstatus"

  # - debug: var=provisioningstatus
```

Here is the output from the Ansible debug:

```html
ok: [localhost] => {
"provisioningstatus": [
    {
        "id": "/subscriptions/redacted/resourceGroups/Tes1Pod/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/vm_deploy_xxxxxxxx",
        "name": "vm_deploy_xxxxxxxx",
        "properties": {
            "correlationId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "debugSetting": null,
            "dependencies": [
                {
                    "dependsOn": [
                        {
                            "id": "/subscriptions/redacted/resourceGroups/Tes1Pod/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/gtsNSG",
                            "resourceGroup": "Tes1Pod",
                            "resourceName": "gtsNSG",
                            "resourceType": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "/subscriptions/redacted/resourceGroups/Tes1Pod/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/gtsPublicIP",
                            "resourceGroup": "Tes1Pod",
                            "resourceName": "gtsPublicIP",
                            "resourceType": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses"
                        }
                    ],
                    "id": "/subscriptions/redacted/resourceGroups/Tes1Pod/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/gtsVMNic",
                    "resourceGroup": "Tes1Pod",
                    "resourceName": "gtsVMNic",
                    "resourceType": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces"
                },
                {
                    "dependsOn": [
                        {
                            "id": "/subscriptions/redacted/resourceGroups/Tes1Pod/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/gtsVMNic",
                            "resourceGroup": "Tes1Pod",
                            "resourceName": "gtsVMNic",
                            "resourceType": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces"
                        }
                    ],
                    "id": "/subscriptions/redacted/resourceGroups/Tes1Pod/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/gts",
                    "resourceGroup": "Tes1Pod",
                    "resourceName": "gts",
                    "resourceType": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
                }
            ],
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "outputs": {},
            "parameters": {},
            "parametersLink": null,
            "providers": [
                {
                    "id": null,
                    "namespace": "Microsoft.Network",
                    "registrationState": null,
                    "resourceTypes": [
                        {
                            "aliases": null,
                            "apiVersions": null,
                            "locations": [
                                "eastus2"
                            ],
                            "properties": null,
                            "resourceType": "networkSecurityGroups"
                        },
                        {
                            "aliases": null,
                            "apiVersions": null,
                            "locations": [
                                "eastus2"
                            ],
                            "properties": null,
                            "resourceType": "publicIPAddresses"
                        },
                        {
                            "aliases": null,
                            "apiVersions": null,
                            "locations": [
                                "eastus2"
                            ],
                            "properties": null,
                            "resourceType": "networkInterfaces"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": null,
                    "namespace": "Microsoft.Compute",
                    "registrationState": null,
                    "resourceTypes": [
                        {
                            "aliases": null,
                            "apiVersions": null,
                            "locations": [
                                "eastus2"
                            ],
                            "properties": null,
                            "resourceType": "virtualMachines"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
            "template": null,
            "templateLink": null,
            "timestamp": "2017-09-05T19:42:14.572793+00:00"
        },
        "resourceGroup": "Tes1Pod"
    },
    {
        "id": "/subscriptions/redacted/resourceGroups/Tes1Pod/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/vm_deploy_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "name": "vm_deploy_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "properties": {
            "correlationId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "debugSetting": null,
            "dependencies": [
                {
                    "dependsOn": [
                        {
                            "id": "/subscriptions/redacted/resourceGroups/Tes1Pod/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/cbrNSG",
                            "resourceGroup": "Tes1Pod",
                            "resourceName": "cbrNSG",
                            "resourceType": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "/subscriptions/redacted/resourceGroups/Tes1Pod/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/cbrPublicIP",
                            "resourceGroup": "Tes1Pod",
                            "resourceName": "cbrPublicIP",
                            "resourceType": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses"
                        }
                    ],
                    "id": "/subscriptions/redacted/resourceGroups/Tes1Pod/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/cbrVMNic",
                    "resourceGroup": "Tes1Pod",
                    "resourceName": "cbrVMNic",
                    "resourceType": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces"
                },
                {
                    "dependsOn": [
                        {
                            "id": "/subscriptions/redacted/resourceGroups/Tes1Pod/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/cbrVMNic",
                            "resourceGroup": "Tes1Pod",
                            "resourceName": "cbrVMNic",
                            "resourceType": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces"
                        }
                    ],
                    "id": "/subscriptions/redacted/resourceGroups/Tes1Pod/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/cbr",
                    "resourceGroup": "Tes1Pod",
                    "resourceName": "cbr",
                    "resourceType": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
                }
            ],
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "outputs": {},
            "parameters": {},
            "parametersLink": null,
            "providers": [
                {
                    "id": null,
                    "namespace": "Microsoft.Network",
                    "registrationState": null,
                    "resourceTypes": [
                        {
                            "aliases": null,
                            "apiVersions": null,
                            "locations": [
                                "eastus2"
                            ],
                            "properties": null,
                            "resourceType": "networkSecurityGroups"
                        },
                        {
                            "aliases": null,
                            "apiVersions": null,
                            "locations": [
                                "eastus2"
                            ],
                            "properties": null,
                            "resourceType": "publicIPAddresses"
                        },
                        {
                            "aliases": null,
                            "apiVersions": null,
                            "locations": [
                                "eastus2"
                            ],
                            "properties": null,
                            "resourceType": "networkInterfaces"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": null,
                    "namespace": "Microsoft.Compute",
                    "registrationState": null,
                    "resourceTypes": [
                        {
                            "aliases": null,
                            "apiVersions": null,
                            "locations": [
                                "eastus2"
                            ],
                            "properties": null,
                            "resourceType": "virtualMachines"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
            "template": null,
            "templateLink": null,
            "timestamp": "2017-09-05T19:42:11.590506+00:00"
        },
        "resourceGroup": "Tes1Pod"
    }
]
}
```

So basically I want to get the properties.Provisioningstate for each item (succeeded or not). I can't get ansible to map these even though I am trying to do so valiantly.

Output from ansible converts to JSON, but I can't select or map the attribute. I always get errors about various things not working (aka can't find property blah).

Main errors are simply not being able to extract the provisioningstatus.properties.provisioningState every time I do I get an 'undefined variable' message.

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "provisioningstatus.properties": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

Comment: Can you replace the sample output here with the output of an ansible `debug` tasks showing the contents of the `provisioningstatus` variable? And can you also show exactly what sort of failures you are experiencing (both the specific error messages and the tasks that generate them)?

Comment: I will do that. Some oitput to follow in about an hour

Comment: Done. I have updated the question as asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.properties.provisioningState }}"
  with_items: "{{ provisioningstatus }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

while not exactly an answer to you question, I suggest you use arm template deployment steps in your ansible configuration. they track the state for you and are idempotent (which is what you want anyway).

```
- name: Deploy Something
  azure_rm_deployment:
    deployment_name: SomeDeploymentName
    resource_group_name: "{{ variable }}"
    location: '{{ location }}'
    template: "{{ lookup('file', './templates/azuredeploy.json') }}"
    parameters:
      deploymentPrefix:
        value: "{{ variable }}"
      redisCacheNames:
        value: "xxx"
```